# python tornado get response of multiple async httprequest

Tags: python, http, asynchronous, request, tornado

i have a list of url_handler and i would want to make asyncronous httprequest using tornado. When all response structure is arrived i need to use it for other targets.
Here a simple example of my code:

```
(...)
self.number = 0
self.counter = 0
self.data = {}
(...)
@tornado.web.asynchronous
def post(self):
    list_url = [url_service1, url_service2]
    self.number = len(list_url)
    http_client = AsyncHTTPClient()
    for service in list_url:
        request = tornado.httpclient.HTTPRequest(url=service, method='POST', headers={'content-type': 'application/json'}, body=json.dumps({..params..}))
        http_client.fetch(request, callback=self.handle_response)

    # Loop for is finished. Use self.data for example in other funcions...
    # if i print(self.data) i have empty dict...
    # do_something(self.data)



def handle_response(self,response):
    if response.error:
        print("Error")
    else:
        self.counter = self.counter + 1
        print("Response {} / {} from {}".format(self.counter, self.number, response.effective_url))
        self.data[response.effective_url] = json_decode(response.body)
    # number is 2
    if self.counter == self.number:
        print("Finish response")

def do_something(data):
    # code with data parameter
```

I hope my problem is well explained

Comment: The code looks alright. What is the problem?

Comment: the row "print(self.data)" prints empty dictionary. I want to get all responses that after async request in for cycle and use them in other functions. For example:
for (...):
    ...
    ...
    fetch(...)

do_something(self.data)--> self.data is empty! How can i have the result of fetch in global variable after callback "handle_response" finishes? The function do_something is outside the callback.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you know `AsyncHTTPClient` is asynchronous, that means, the requests will run in *background*.

So, when the `for` loop is finished, that does not mean all the requests are also finished - they are running in the background even when the loop finishes.

That is why `self.data` is empty, because the requests aren't completed yet.

---

**How to fix this**

As you know the `handle_response` callback is called after every request is completed. You can call `do_something` function from this callback when all the requests are completed. Like this:

```
def handle_response(...):
    ...
    if self.counter == self.number:
        self.do_something(self.data)
        print("Finish response")
```

Comment: @LucaPalombella Yes, if you're using callbacks like this, then that is a good place to write the results.